# How to update/ delete a key from a context in Odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Hi i am trying to delete a key value from the context for `res.partner` form view.

I opening the `partner form view` using `controller` function and trying to set phone number as default and its working fine. But when i try to create a new customer by clicking on the create button the `phone` number again auto-filled. In order to avoid this behaviour, in `default_get` function, i copied the context into another variable,  removed the `key value` from the context using `del context['cc_mobile']`. And reassigned to `self.env.context`. But when i try to create a new customer, the deleted `key value` comes in the context again.

**Controller.py**

```
@http.route('/open_customer/<string:val>', type="http",method=['POST','GET'],website=False, auth="public")
def open_case_window(self,**kw):
    mobile_no = kw.get('val')
    action = request.env.ref('base.action_partner_form').sudo()
    mobile_flag = 0
    partner = 'res.partner'
    partner_model = request.env[partner]
    regex = re.match( '^(?:\01|02|03|04|06|07|09)\d*$', mobile_no)
    if regex:
        mobile_flag = 0
        partner_id = partner_model.search([('phone', '=', mobile_no)]).id
    else:
        mobile_flag = 1
        partner_id = partner_model.search([('mobile','=',mobile_no)]).id

    if partner_id:
        return werkzeug.utils.redirect('/web#id='+str(partner_id)+'&view_type=form&model='+partner)
    else:
        context = dict(action._context)
        if mobile_flag == 0:
            context.update({'cc_phone': mobile_no})
        else:
            context.update({'cc_mobile': mobile_no})
        context.pop('lang')
        url = werkzeug.utils.redirect('/web?debug=#view_type=form&model='+str(partner)+'&action=%s'%(action.id))
        return url
```

**ResPartner.py**

```
 @api.model
def default_get(self, fields):
    context = self.env.context.copy()
    print'default_get context',context
    res = super(Partner, self).default_get(fields)
    if 'cc_mobile' in context:
        res.update({'mobile':context.get('cc_mobile')})
    if 'cc_phone' in context:
        res.update({'phone':context.get('cc_phone')})
    if context.get('cc_mobile'):
        del context['cc_mobile']
    if context.get('cc_phone'):
        del context['cc_phone']
    self.env.context = context
    print'self.env.context after',self.env.context
    action = self.env.ref('base.action_partner_form').sudo()
    action.env.context = self.env.context
    return res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove a `key` of action `context` from python side, because it's in the `client` side. when ever you call the server like `search` in `many2one` field, `create` a record in fly you will see this `context` comeback again every time (The way Odoo work).

What you need is something that will be used for one time, I think you need some kind of persistence for example:

1. dummy model that contains `user_id, model_name, value, active` fields so in the controller you create a record for default value for that specific user.
2. get that value by overriding `default_get` by searching with `user_id` and `model_name` field and **hide** that value or **delete** it.

this way when yo hit create button or create contact in fly when you search for the value it will be gone so it will not be used a second time.

This a simple Idea and easy to implement, you need to handle some cases to prevent user from saving two default value if some interruption happens should not be hard.

**Edit**

After second thought to prevent any error when you create a record just pass it's ID in the context with a special key, then use That Id to retrieve it, use it then delete it. easier, safer and no need for search.